# How can I monitor per process/per thread memory consumption (divided into heap, stack, data, code)?

Tags: linux, memory, stack

Before jumping in and writing my own code, I want to find out if there is GNU/Linux software that is able to output something similar to [QNX's `showmem`](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0_sp1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities%2Fs%2Fshowmem.html&cp=13_13_21_15).

For each thread of each process that is running, I would like to see the memory consumption divided into the following categories:

```
 Process listing (Total, Code, Data, Heap, Stack, Other)
 319488  1024000      24587     167936      24576          0        4103 devc-con-hid (thread 2)
    0          0          0          0       4096          0        4103 devc-con-hid (thread 2)
    0          0          0          0      20480          0        4103 devc-con-hid (thread 1)
    0     102400       8192          0          0          0        4103 devc-con-hid (proc/boot/devc-con-hid)
    0          0      16384          0          0          0        4103 devc-con-hid (proc/boot/libc.so.3)
    0          0          0          0          0  (   36864)       4103 devc-con-hid (/dev/mem)
```

Is there anything that will make this possible?

Comment: Looks like most of this info is in `/proc/$PID/smaps`

Comment: That's right, but I was hoping there is some tool that I can run and automatically outputs the memory information.

Comment: I'm sure there are memory profilers out there for someone with specific needs. Most people could just periodically save the contents of that proc file. FWIW it sounds like [one of valgrind's components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633089/good-memory-profiler-for-64-bit-linux) has a pretty good profiler. I've never used it but maybe it's a direction for you to go into.

Answer (score 7):

You can see some information using `pmap -x PID` - it's divided into kbytes, rss and dirty memory for each library/module/open file/stack of a process:

```
undefine@uml:~$ pmap -x 13206
13206:   sleep 60
Address           Kbytes     RSS   Dirty Mode  Mapping
0000000000400000      24      20       0 r-x-- sleep
0000000000606000       4       4       4 r---- sleep
0000000000607000       4       4       4 rw--- sleep
000000000063b000     132       8       8 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f6a9847e000    4308      44       0 r---- locale-archive
00007f6a988b3000    1772     376       0 r-x-- libc-2.19.so
00007f6a98a6e000    2048       0       0 ----- libc-2.19.so
00007f6a98c6e000      16      16      16 r---- libc-2.19.so
00007f6a98c72000       8       8       8 rw--- libc-2.19.so
00007f6a98c74000      20      12      12 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f6a98c79000     140     116       0 r-x-- ld-2.19.so
00007f6a98e71000      12      12      12 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f6a98e99000       8       8       8 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f6a98e9b000       4       4       4 r---- ld-2.19.so
00007f6a98e9c000       4       4       4 rw--- ld-2.19.so
00007f6a98e9d000       4       4       4 rw---   [ anon ]
00007fff09fd0000     132      12      12 rw---   [ stack ]
00007fff09ffe000       8       4       0 r-x--   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000       4       0       0 r-x--   [ anon ]
---------------- ------- ------- ------- 
total kB            8652     656      96
```